# PHP Warning: open_basedir restriction in effect

Tags: php, vps, laravel-8

he desplegado un proyecto nuevo de laravel 8 en mi VPS en desarrollo y me arroja error 500 en el servidor.

He probado con "composer install", a cambiarle los permisos a "bootstrap/cache" y "storage".

Adjunto fichero log del servidor, creo que es algo relacionado con el open_basedir de PHP pero no se exactamente como meterle mano.

Un saludo y gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puede ser que la configuración de PHP no permita acceder a archivos que estén por fuera de la carpeta public_html. Si tenés acceso completo al servidor podrías intentar modificar la configuración `open_basedir` en php.ini agregando esos paths.

Comment: ¿En qué carpeta tienes `vendor/autoload.php`? Si está dentro de `public_html/` entonces el problema es de rutas, no la estás especificando correctamente; si está en el mismo nivel que `public_html/` entonces es cuestión de permisos.

Comment: Es un VPS en Debian. El proyecto está en -> /home/usuario/web/midominio.com/  ---- De aquí cuelgan todas las carpetas de Laravel y el public_hml por lo que en el index.php la ruta estaría bien del modo "../vendor/autoload.php"